# Why did Deadly Viper Assassination Squad stop operating?

Tags: plot-explanation, kill-bill

Four and a half years after the massacre in El Paso, the Deadly Viper Assassination Squad does not operate any more. Its members no longer work together. I understand that Bill and his brother had a falling out.

Apparently other team members are at least on speaking terms.

What happened? Why did their team fall apart?

Comment: Simple speculation here: After El Paso, there's a change in Bill's lifestyle that might have made it harder for him to keep the team in line: he has a new daughter to take care of. Unless I've forgotten a detail and there was someone else raising her...

Comment: I think this is a correct explanation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the answer to it is that "Viper Assassination Squad" went through a disbandment.
Beatrix was killed by the squad, Bill and Bud have a fallout, O-ren-ishi always had a long term plan of establishing herself in the Tokyo underworld, so she pursues that and Bill approves if it because we know that Bill helped her in that. So in this way, one by one the members leave due to one reason or the other and the squad is dibanded. This leads to squad stop operating. I mean I am trying to relate the whole thing like it happens with the bands (music) when one or more members leave, it eventually leads to the band stop performing at all.

Comment: What about Elle?